# Incorrect file path from Media Capture plugin in Ionic 3 native

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-native

The `promise<MediaFile[]>` returned by MediaCapture plugin when `this.mediaCapture.captureImage()` is called is returning incorrect `fullPath` of the captured image.

```
MediaFile
end:0
fullPath:"file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1503140105277.jpg"
lastModified:null
lastModifiedDate:1503140121000
localURL:"cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/Pictures/1503140105277.jpg"
name:"1503140105277.jpg"
size:4261137
start:0
type:"image/jpeg"
__proto__:File
length:1
```

I cannot access the file from this fullPath but when i use the FileChooser Plugin and gets the file URI by this code:

```
this.fileChooser.open()
        .then(uri => {
          console.log('from file chooser: ',uri);
          this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
          .then(filePath => {
            console.log('from filepath: ',filePath);
            this.navCtrl.push('NewPostPage', {
              mediaFile : filePath
            })
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The filepath returned by this is:

```
from file chooser:  content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A13988 
from filepath:  file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170819_155509.jpg
```

You can see both the file paths from `mediaCapture` plugin returned promise and `FileChooser` plugin is different:

```
MediaCapture: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1503140105277.jpg"
FileChooser: "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170819_155509.jpg"
```

I easily gets the image from `FileChooser` returned string. But i cannot use the fileChooser plugin tell me what should i do, or where i went wrong.